# Error on Creating Stored Function in MySQL 5.0.5

Tags: mysql, function, syntax-error

I'm usually working with mssql or postgres, but I need to use MySql in the current project.
Now I have a problem with creating a stored function in MySQL 5.0.5.
I'm getting the following error:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

My Code looks like that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION aip_sf_choice_valid (request_id INT)
 RETURNS INT
 BEGIN
  DECLARE sf_result INT;
  SET sf_result = 1;
 RETURN sf_result
END
```

I'm really out of ideas. I'm glad for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the default delimiter from ';' within the SP body.  More info on that here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION aip_sf_choice_valid (request_id INT)
 RETURNS INT
 BEGIN
  DECLARE sf_result INT;
  SET sf_result = 1;
 RETURN sf_result;
END
```

Comment: Thank you very mcuh for your help! That is the answer! I really was stuck!

Answer (score 0):

Should it have a semicolon after "END"?

Comment: No, that doesn't help neither, but thank you for the try. I'm glad for every answer!